# WatchKit App doesn't contain any WatchKit Extensions

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, info.plist

While archiving an iOS app on Xcode during the compilation phase;
I get the error -

"error: WatchKit App doesn't contain any WatchKit Extensions. Verify that the value of NSExtensionPointIdentifier in your WatchKit Extension's Info.plist is set to com.apple.watchkit." even though I have confirmed that this is set correct.

Then, why is this happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check build settings in watchappextension target if you have correct watch extension Info.plist file path. In my case, i had watch plist set.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. To solve that, I've modified the extension identifier so that it has watchkit's identifier as prefix. This is because, unless identifiers are prefix, those won't be allowed to embed on Xcode settings.

Check list:

1. In main iOS app settings on general tab, add your watchkit app in the embedded binaries section. Note that, if you ever deleted build folder, the embedded watchkit app may not be displayed in this section even if you just added there.
   [image: App Settings, General Tab]
2. Make sure you see the watchkit app both in target dependancy & embedded binaries section. If not, add them on the build phases tab of your iOS app.
   [image: App Settings, Build Phases Tab]
3. Now on settings of watchkit app, add your extension in the embedded binaries.
   [image: Watchkit Settings, General Tab]
4. You should see the watchkit extension both in target dependancy & embedded binaries section. If not, add them on the build phases tab of your watchkit app.
   [image: Watchkit Settings, Build Phases Tab]
5. On build settings of the extension, make sure bitcode is enabled. Base sdk should be latest iOS sdk.
   [image: Watchkit Extension Settings, Build Settings Tab]
6. See the watchkit app identifier is a prefix of the extension. I've renamed the product module (both for watchkit app & extension) to avoid spaces.
   [image: Watchkit Extension > Build Settings > Packaging]

You should now be able to build or archive with proper mobile provisions. By the way, my Xcode version is 9.3.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise, be sure you tailor your answer to *this* question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Hi @EdCottrell, I'm sure following the same process (my checklist), will solve 2 different issues. I've faced both issues- (1) watchkit app has no extension while building/archiving (2) after uploading to appstore- expected app is missing from the app’s root location. That's why answered both askers as I've rigorously checked those while looking for solution. But thank you for your suggestion, will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Exit XCode, remove derived data, start XCode again and clean project